# How to disable localization for a JAR file?

Tags: java, localization, jar

I have a JAR file that has localization for my language, but I don't want it to use that, I want it to be in English.

Does anyone have any idea how to run a JAR file in English, or how to remove localization from a JAR file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [exampledepot.com](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/SetDefLocale.html):

```
> java -Duser.language=2-char-lang-code -Duser.region=2-char-country-code MyApp

// Set only language code
> java -Duser.language=fr -Duser.region= MyApp

// Set language and country code
> java -Duser.language=fr -Duser.region=CA MyApp
```

The code for english is `en`.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I didn't find this! Anyways, a few more minutes and I'll accept your answer :)